# login with dojo post request to extern server

Tags: javascript, authentication, dojo

I am trying to write a login function with dojo. In my case, I need a post request to a extern (!!) server in this case:

login is defined as followed:

> **login**
>
> Login is a special action, not handling any data, but authenticating a user. A POST request is to be made, containing a json object with keys 'email' and 'password'. The return value is either true or false. A special Cookie is returned for further identification.
>
> **Valid API Calls**
>
> URL: /api/login
>
> Method: POST
>
> **Fields:**
>
> email
>
> password
>
> **Description:** Returns all data for the logged in user in PLIST format. if login fails, false is returned in PLIST format.

Well, I tried to solve that problem with a io.iframe.send call, but i get the following error: Error: Permission denied to access property 'getElementsByTagName'

However, I am even not sure, if io.iframe is the correct way to solve my problem.

Perhaps you can help me
Thanks a lot

PS: My current code looks like this:

```
function login(){
    require(["dojo/io/iframe", "dojo/dom"], function(iframe, dom){
        var email = dom.byId("logEmail").value;
        var password = dom.byId("logPassword").value;

        function JSONreq(){

            var jsonpArgs = {
                method: 'POST',
                handleAs:"json",
                content:{
                    email: email,
                    password: password

                },
                url: "http://---someServerThatIDontWantToName---/api2/login",
                load: function (response, ioargs){
                    //console.log(response)
                    alert('succes');
                },
                error: function(response, ioargs){
                    alert("error");
                }
            };
            iframe.send(jsonpArgs);
        }
        dojo.ready(JSONreq);

    });
};
```

---

is there any difference in mobile development? cross server post requests should be possible on a mobile device.

so: can i use io.iframe.send for this reason?

Comment: you can use jsonp or call to your domaind and send params via curl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anser in short is, you cannot at any given time use POST request on a X-domain via browser client. Reason is, the DOM is protected on another namespace and what is happening through io.iframe is;

1. establish GET request
2. find form, check foreach (local) name/value content keypair if (remote) input exists

   - if not exists, create as such: `dojo.create("input", {type: "hidden", name: name, value: value}, fn);`
   - else if it does, set the value on form.element-of-name.

So, first of all DOM lookup will fail in 2) due to security restrictions, meaning 'not exists', then in turn, 2.1) dojo.create will fail with same reason.

Typical workarounds are

1. Open GET method in your x-domainserver/api/login (set url: prefix + dojo.formToQuery(form)
2. Create an in which url refreshes on a  polling interval, making login keep-alive
3. Create a 'jumphost' on your samehost-server/api/login/passthrough which serverside does POST to x-domainserver/api/login, then returns result. Giving PHP solution for this

   $allowedDomains = array(
       "http://facebook.whatever.org/", 
       "http://yournavigation.org/");

   // The target request uri on x-domain, say "form action"
   $action = $_REQUEST["url"];

   // Method only looks for POST and defaults GET
   $method = $_REQUEST["method"];

   // Query placeholder, filled by rolling through _REQUEST, will append all but method / url pairs
   $fields = "";

   // Authorize against allowedDomains or die

   foreach ($allowedDomains as $domain) {

   ```
   if (strpos(substr($action, 0, strlen($domain)), $domain) !== false) {
   header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden");
   die("Domain name "".$action."" not allowed. Access denied.");
   flush();
   }
   ```

   }

   if (count($_REQUEST) > 2) {

   ```
   foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {

       if ($key != "url" && $key != "method") // append anything but url and method
           $fields .= $key . "=" . rawurlencode($value) . "&";
   }
   ```

   }
   $fields = substr($fields, 0, strlen($fields) - 1);

   // Setup curl
   $ch = curl_init();
   if (strtoupper($method) == "POST") {
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $action);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
   } else {
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $action . "?" . $fields);
   }
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "transport.php (CURL)");

   // Send, catch returning response and close
   $response = curl_exec($ch);
   $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
   curl_close($ch);

   // Reply response to client XHR
   header("Content-type: ".$info["content_type"]);
   echo $response;

Answer (score 1):

You can send POST request to another domain with target iframe, but can not read any property or DOM node from that iframe.

There's `XHR2`, but it is not supported in all browsers and server should return specific headers. ANd I'm not sure you one can send POST via XHR2.

Comment: Unfortunately the posts do not help me a lot... perhaps it helps you, when I tell you, that this is going to be a mobile application. I am using dojo and phonegap. My get requests work fine, but how the login docu shows, I need a post request for the final login.